# If the Pod state is "Failed" does that imply "Failed Terminally" or "Failed but may restart"?

Tags: kubernetes

Assume the following sequence:

1. My pod includes a single container. The pod has `RestartPolicy=OnFailure`
2. The pod's container exits with a non-zero status
3. The container will be restarted due to the RestartPolicy

It seems there are two possible behaviors. Will the pod Phase be `Failed` before it restarts? Or will the container restart directly?

Which pattern will the pod phase follow?

a) `Pending > Running > Failed > Running`
b) `Pending > Running`

I can't tell which of these two options is implied by the [Kubernetes RestartPolicy documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy).